# Search $\nu$ index for the sequence $\{n^n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

It is easy to calculate the following limit of the sequence $\{n^n\}$.
In fact $\lim _{n\to \infty }n^n=+\infty$ apply simply the exponent rule $ \:n^n=e^{\ln \left(n^n\right)}=e^{n\cdot \ln \left(n\right)}$. To prove that

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }n^n=+\infty \iff \forall k>0, \exists \ \nu\in\mathbb N: n^n\geq k,\ \ \forall n\in\mathbb N,\ n>\nu$$

Now let be $n\geq 2$ then is true $n^n\geq 2^n$. We know that $\nu:= \nu(k)$, and being $n\to\infty$, $n^n\geq 2^n\geq k$.

> Is it correct, to take $\nu=\max\{[\log_2k],1\}$ also for the index of the sequence $\{n^n\}$ or is there another solution?

Comment: @downvoter: What is the reason for this downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use the inequality
$$n^n\gt n\quad \forall n\gt1$$

Comment: Thank you very very much for to have accept my request.